# OpenCV cvCaptureFromCAM(0) doesn't work

Tags: opencv, video-capture

I am trying to use a webcam to simulate as a camera for lane detection. When I try to use a webcam (with function `cvCaptureFromCAM(0)`), the frame is blank. However, input_video does not give a NULL value, meaning that there is some connection between the program and the webcam, but the video does not show

```
int main(int, char)
{
input_video = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);

if (input_video == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Can't open video\n");

    return -1;
}

while (key_pressed != 27) {

    frame = cvQueryFrame(input_video);
    if (frame == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: null frame received\n");
        return -1;
    }
```

However, using the same code, using a AVI file, the video displays. How do I proceed on? Much help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you play the webcam using `VLC` or some other application?

Comment: yes, i am able to open my webcam using VLC

Comment: Try passing `CV_CAP_ANY` instead of `0`.

Comment: Tried using CV_CAP_ANY, but the camera does not seem to display the frame as well.

Comment: @TiewWeiJian Is there a particular reason for using the OpenCV C API?

Comment: It was a school project that was written in C. Is there a better alternative compared to C language?

Comment: Yes, use C++ API.

Comment: Blank as in all zeros or constant?  You might be missing the 3rd party library support needed to interface with the webcam.  You should check how OpenCV was compiled.